# python multiprocessing.Array typing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, type-hinting, python-typing

When creating an array, I want to put it inside a dataclass, but I cannot find the type of the returned object.

`arr =  multiprocessing.RawArray("i", 2)`

If I do:

```
>>> type(arr)
<class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_long_Array_2'>
```

but `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_long_Array_2` does not exists.
How can I use type hints, e.g `arr: the_type` with multiprocessing Array?

**UPDATE**
Pycharm example when using typing `ctypes.c_long * 2`, there's still a value attribute which is invalid.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared array's type is derived from the `ctypes` module. You could also perhaps use this module to help you be more explicit about the data type of the array:

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes # This is what you're looking for

# Your function that you want to type-hint for
def func(arr: ctypes.c_long * 2):
    # Some operations
    ...

# Being explicit about which c-type i want my array to be
arr = multiprocessing.RawArray(ctypes.c_long, 2)

# This evaluates to true
print(isinstance(arr, ctypes.c_long * 2))
```

Note: `ctypes` does not come with all the possibilities of array sizes so notice the `ctypes.c_long * 2` syntax to indicate that it is an array of `long` of `size = 2`.

Comment: thanks, though the typing doesn't seem to be very accurate, 
`ctypes.c_long * 2` results in type that has `.value` attribute, while RawArray doesn't have it.
Also, the resulted type doesn't have `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` that RawArray has. Checked in pycharm. Why is that?  Though, the type itself does match to what multiprocessing.RawArray returns.

Comment: Not sure why that is happening for you. They appear to be the exact same on my end with the exception of an extra '_wrapper' attribute in the `multiprocessing.RawArray` instance.

Comment: Gave it another thought, are you sure you are annotating it as `ctypes.c_long * 2` instead of just `ctypes.c_long` without the `*2`? Cus it seems like you are creating a scalar instead of an array which explains why there is a `.value` attribute and without the `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` methods

Comment: In fact, I am pretty certain you made a typo somewhere using a scalar instead of having the `* 2` to indicate it as an array

Comment: Correction, there are `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, but there's still a `.value` attribute for some reason..

Comment: Would be helpful if you shared the code that led to this outcome

Comment: Added a screenshot from pycharm, you can see that pycharm autocomplete gives .value and .raw attributes. (In addition to `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`)

Comment: @user3599803 that seems to be PyCharm's issue of mis-interpreting. You can verify by printing `dir(arr)` to see what are actually available. Or try accessing `arr.value` to see that it throws an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Once verified, you can mark this as answered and raise a new question for your new issue of text editor misinterpreting type.

Comment: yes, dir(arr) doesn't show .value attribute. So I guess it is something with pycharm

Comment: good to know! cheers! If its of any further help, I checked as well on VSCode and it seems like your problem is not limited to PyCharm.